# Cannot import module after installing, Anaconda/Spyder/Jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, spyder

I installed opencv by using the windows command prompt and entered: `pip install opencv-python`

I verified that it installed by entering `python` followed by `import cv2`

`>>> import cv2`

I did not receive any error messages, in fact received no message at all, which indicates to me everything installed correctly.

However, when I attempt to `import cv2` on Spyder IDE or on Jupyter Notebook, I get the following error:

*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'*

I've tried reinstalling it, tried to install it through Anaconda prompt, and tried looking for solutions in other forums, but cannot seem to solve why I cannot `import cv2`.

I am able to import other modules such as `import numpy`. Please help, thank you.

1st Edit:
I open Juypter Notebook with Python 3 (ipykernel), and my system runs Python 3.10.5

2nd Edit:
I originally installed Spyder alone without Anaconda. However, recently I downloaded both Jupyter and Spyder through Anaconda. I downloaded it from the official Anaconda website: https://www.anaconda.com/

So yes! I did install them as part of the Anaconda platform.

3rd Edit:
I see your point. I believe you, it most likely is a environment problem. I have only downloaded one version of Python, which is 3.10.5.

I have not downloaded any other "Pythons". I do have multiple IDEs however such as Notepad++. However, no previous versions of Python are on this computer.

You are right about me running into this problem with other packages! I am currently also attempting to `pip install scikit-learn`. However, when I `import sklearn`, I also obtain an error:

*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'*

Do you know how I can fix that to locate the packages for both Spyder and Jupyter? I tried to configure the settings as the previous comment said, but I'm probably not doing it correctly.

Comment: Make sure you start Jupyter with the same Python version. For Spider, check its configuration settings: there's probably a path to the relevant Python executable that can be changed.

Comment: Did you install Spyder and Jupyter as part of the Anaconda platform?

Comment: messed up environments. how many pythons do you have? are you messing around with any type of "virtual" environments? it's really not an opencv problem because this can happen with any other package you try to install. you were able to import numpy because that's likely already installed in all your environments because it's a common dependency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple Python installations on your system.

The one you are accessing form the Windows command prompt is your system-wide Python installation. If you run `python -V` in the cmd, you should see version 3.10.5 which you said you have deployed.

At the same time, you have at least one other Python installation that came with Anaconda. If you open Anaconda prompt, you should see a `(base)` prefix before the regular path prompt. This prefix indicates that you are in a separate Python environment managed by `conda`. If you run `python -V` there, you should see a different Python version.

If you can confirm that the versions are different, than what happens is that you install packages in one Python environment (system-wide), while trying to use them in the other Python environment which is not aware of them.

Your Jupyter Notebook, as well as Spyder IDE, most likely, are using your `base` Anaconda environment. To install packages in it use Anaconda prompt, verify that you can see `(base)` prefix in the prompt, and use `conda install` or `pip install` in there.

To better understand how Python environments can be managed with conda, have a look [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html).

Comment: Awesome thank you! So I actually did try to install opencv on Anaconda prompt, but there were some issues. I'll create a new post for that one.

Comment: If ```pip install``` fails to install a package in a conda environment, you can try to install it with ```conda install``` instead. Conda has package repositories with packages specifically created for it. OpenCV is available: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/opencv

Comment: @PKrange You can use the magic commands, such as `%conda install <package-name>`, when inside Jupyter to insure the installations go to where Jupyter is using. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about these magic commands. It can be helpful to get you past environment hurdles.